# Swift: Up Cast NSManagedObject to subclass Entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

How do I up cast `NSManagedObject` to subclass entity called `Relationship` in Swift .

```
func processEntity(updates: [NSManagedObject]) -> [Relationship] {
        let relationship = updates.filter({$0.entity.name == "Relationship"} 
        // here how do I return an array of [Relationship] 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't compare names, just do a normal cast.

```
func processEntity(updates: [NSManagedObject]) -> [Relationship] {
    return updates.flatMap({ $0 as? Relationship })
}
```

If you're unfamiliar with it, `flatMap` is basically a `filter` plus a `map`. If the block returns `nil`, the element is omitted from the resulting array, otherwise the array will contain the value returned by the block. So in this case we're looking at every `NSManagedObject` and saying "are you really a `Relationship`?", and we keep the values that are `Relationship`s.

Comment: @Abizern Please do not remove my parentheses. See [The Rule of Kevin](http://ericasadun.com/2015/11/17/a-handful-of-swift-style-rules-swiftlang/).

Comment: Sorry, just trying to be helpful, but the link lets me see what you mean now. Thanks.